# WPF How to reuse Popup window xaml fragment to show on multiple different button clicks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, popupwindow

I have a created a Popup window in xaml which is opened on clicking a button. I need the same Popup on clicking some other button. Is there a clean way to reuse this popup without copy pasting it directly inplace?

Comment: Let me guess, you did this on code and not XAML ? Show  some code and xaml. without those nobody can help you.

Answer (score 2):

using MVVM you can simply bind its `IsOpen` property to your ViewModel and have both buttons change it to true.

here is an example using [Prism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx), but can easily be implemented by any other MVVM framework:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    x:Name="mainWindow">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="First Button" Command="{Binding CommandA}"/>
         <Button Content="Second Button" Command="{Binding CommandB}"/>  
    </StackPanel>

    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           Width="100"
           Height="100">
        <Border Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="This is my popup"/>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

VM:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CommandA = new DelegateCommand(() => IsOpen = true);
        CommandB = new DelegateCommand(() => IsOpen = true);
    }

    public DelegateCommand CommandA { get; set; }
    public DelegateCommand CommandB { get; set; }

    private bool isOpen;

    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return isOpen; }
        set
        {
            isOpen = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => IsOpen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it.  Thanks. If I want to use it across windows then should extend the Popup class. Is there a way to do it without extending for such case?